Angular Material Paginator doesn't display all pageSizeOptions
When I click on the select element, nothing happens, even though the options should appear. They don't appear in DevTools either.
<mat-paginator 
    [length]="totalApplications" 
    [pageSize]="pageSize" 
    [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
    showFirstLastButtons="true"
    (page)="onPageChange($event)">
  </mat-paginator>

dataSource: any[] = [];
    totalApplications = this.fullData.length;
    pageSizeOptions = [10, 20, 50];
    pageSize = 20;
    currentPage = 0;
    
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.updatePageData();
    }

    onPageChange(event: any): void {
      this.currentPage = event.pageIndex;
      this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
      this.updatePageData();
    }

    updatePageData(): void {
      const startIndex = this.currentPage * this.pageSize;
      const endIndex = startIndex + this.pageSize;
      this.dataSource = this.fullData.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    }

I added these styles to check if the select options are maybe overridden by other elements, but still, nothing changed.
mat-paginator {
  display: block !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}


Would be great if you can reproduce the issue in StackBlitz. Which Angular Material version you used?

I managed to solve the issue. The problem was due to hiding the overlay container:
styles.scss
.cdk-overlay-container {
    display: none !important;
}

After removing that, the options were displayed.
I added the display: none in the first place because the overlay containers used to be positioned wrongly before adding the paginator, but this solved the position issue:
styles.scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();


don't forget to mark this answer as accepted! :)
